# Подскажите, как сделать имитацию движущейся машины по горизонтали

Tags: swift, spritekit

Подскажите, как сделать имитацию движущегося автомобиля по горизонтали с остановкой в нужном месте, а затем продолжить движение

ширина фона 20000px
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое направление двигаться
какие методы использовать

Answer (score 0):

Начните с туториалов, например вот этого:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/71-spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! 
 Реализовать движение фона не составила труда
методов реализации много через 
SKAction.move, SKCameraNode, func update.

 Может я не правильно задал вопрос.
Меня по большей степени интересует как реализовать остановки в нужном месте для определенных действий и потом продолжить движение

Comment: Какие действия вы имеете ввиду, тапы по экрану? Есть различные функции touches..., посмотрите их.

Comment: Благодарю за Ваше участие! Нет не тап! фон составляет около 20000px в ширину, нужно к примеру высчитать 4500px и сделать автоматически остановку движения фона собрать что то и после если действия сделаны правильно продолжить движение до отметки грубо говоря 9000px и т.д.

Comment: Добавил картинку как пример

Comment: У SKSpriteNode есть position, сравнивайте при движении текущую позицию ноды с желаемой, при достижении производите действия, как-то так.